# Генерация номера заказа для отслеживания

Tags: php

Разрабатываю сайт для транспортной компании, занимается перевозкой грузов, нужно написать код, который будет генерировать номер для отслеживания, на основе order_id, полученного из бд. Пишу на php.
Уже всю голову сломал, не могу придумать как перенести эту логику с бумаги в код.

Прикреплю описание генерации, если кто-то сможет в этом помочь, буду премного благодарен.[image: описание в фото]

Comment: Ну, самый тупой вариант - это определить 19 границ и использовать base_convert  со своим набором симолов в каждой

Comment: @Ипатьев, не могли бы объяснить поподробнее? Можно в телеге, если Вам удобно будет. Мой ник: "@ceh137"

Comment: я думаю вполне можно погуглить base convert и дальше уже само пойдет